# How can I modify the rx_bytes and tx_bytes fileds of the stats struct of the dev struct

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm going to preserve the rx_bytes and tx_bytes fields of the stats struct of the dev struct after system boot in Ubuntu 22.1 with 5.15.0-69-generic kernel version.

So I wrote a Linux kernel module to get that values as follows and that code works well, but I don't know how can I modify values after system restart.

```c
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h> 
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/netdevice.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>
#include <linux/version.h>

static int mymodule_init(void)
{   
    struct net_device *dev = first_net_device(&init_net);   
    struct net_device_stats *stats;  // Just for a one CPU core
    struct rtnl_link_stats64 *netdev_stats64, stats64; //for All CPU

    printk(KERN_INFO "    Linux Version: %d",LINUX_VERSION_CODE);
    printk(KERN_INFO "    Linux Version: %d",KERNEL_VERSION(2,6,63));

    while(dev) {
        printk("Dev: name: %s - ifindex: %d\n", dev->name, dev->ifindex);
        if (netif_running(dev)) {
            printk(KERN_INFO "     Device is up: True\n"); 
            printk(KERN_INFO "      Device name: %s\n", dev->name);
            printk(KERN_INFO "              MTU: %d\n", dev->mtu);
            printk(KERN_INFO "      Dev Address: %pM\n", dev->dev_addr);
            printk(KERN_INFO "Permanent Address: %pM\n", dev->perm_addr);

            stats = &dev->stats;
            // netdev_stats_show(NULL, &stats);
             
            netdev_stats64 = dev_get_stats(dev, &stats64);

            printk(KERN_INFO "         rx_bytes: %llu\n", (unsigned long long) netdev_stats64->rx_bytes);
            printk(KERN_INFO "         tx_bytes: %llu\n", (unsigned long long) netdev_stats64->tx_bytes);
            printk(KERN_INFO "-------------------------------");
        } else { 
            printk("Device is down\n"); 
        }
        
        if (test_bit(__LINK_STATE_NOCARRIER, &dev->state))
            printk("NOCARRIER set\n");
        else
            printk("NOCARRIER NOT-set\n");

        /* Access the rx_bytes field of the network statistics */
        dev = next_net_device(dev);
    }

    return 0;   
}

static void mymodule_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Info: Module Unloaded...");
}

module_init(mymodule_init);
module_exit(mymodule_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Kiavash Rocky");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Read device structure of a given device file");
```

Anyone can help me how can I do that?

I need to modify the rx_bytes and tx_bytes after system boot with  values that I saved before system restarted.

Comment: ? That just depends on the actual hardware and driver used for the network. https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/net/core/dev.c#L10404 I guess you could add a wrapper around ndo_get_stats/-64 to add them to the network interface. Good luck.

Comment: As I told you already, the variables are per CPU. The access to them has been done accordingly.